# How to join a string escaped csv from an ordered dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to write a string escaped csv.

However, when I run something like this I receive the following error:

`AttributeError: 'odict_values' object has no attribute 'encode'`

```
from collections import OrderedDict
ordered_dict = OrderedDict({
  "hdr_1": "val_1",
  "hdr_2": "val '2'",
  "hdr_3": 3,
  "hdr_4": "val, 4"
})

vals = ','.join(ordered_dict.values().encode('unicode_escape'))
print(vals)
```

Expected output:

```
'val_1','val ''2''',3,'val, 4'
```

How can I write out an escaped csv?

Comment: There's no such format that requires single quotes to be escaped while enclosed in double quotes. You should clarify the logics behind your expected output, which definitely isn't an encoding of `unicode_escape`.

Comment: I've updated the question. The intention is to keep the integrity of the dictionary values when joined into a csv.

Comment: That's an even weirder expected output, with double single quotes enclosed in single quotes. Please explain the logics of the escape.

Comment: I see. If you need to output as CSV use the `csv` module.

Comment: Never mind the "weirder" comment. I just realized that doubling the quotes is actually one of the standard ways of escaping quotes within quotes. I've updated my answer as a result.

Comment: It's all good. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your goal is to produce the output as a row of valid CSV, you can use `csv.DictWriter` to output the dict. Specify the `QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` option for `quoting` if you prefer to force all non-numeric fields to be quoted:

```
import csv
from io import StringIO

output = StringIO()
csv.DictWriter(output, ordered_dict, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC).writerow(ordered_dict)
print(output.getvalue())
```

This outputs:

```
"val_1","val '2'",3
```

If you prefer the quoting character to be a rather unusual single quote, as your expected output indicates, you can specify it as the `quotechar` argument:

```
import csv
from io import StringIO

output = StringIO()
csv.DictWriter(
    output, ordered_dict, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, quotechar="'"
).writerow(ordered_dict)
print(output.getvalue())
```

This outputs:

```
'val_1','val ''2''',3
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you sir!